# Symfony: Call to a member function setPriority() on null

Tags: php, symfony2

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    if ($object->getPriority() === ArticlePriority::DEFAULT) {
        return;
    }

    $repo = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

    $article = $repo->getRepository(Article::class)
                    ->findOneBy(['priority' => $object->getPriority()]);

    $article->setPriority(ArticlePriority::DEFAULT);
    $repo->getManager()->persist($article);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо )) Буду искать сам

Comment: А я похоже вас обманул :) Думаю для начала вам стоит проверить есть ли в базе объект типа `Article` с полем `priority === $object->getPriority()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно документации, метод [`EntityRepository::findOneBy`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#_findOneBy) возвращает либо объект-сущность, либо `null`, если сущность отвечающая критериям поиска не найдена в репозитории.

Похоже, что в вашем случае, не существует объекта `Article` с `Article::$priority === $object->getPriority()`.

Если для вашего приложения это нормальная ситуация, то метод `preUpdate` стоит модифицировать следующим образом:

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    if ($object->getPriority() === ArticlePriority::DEFAULT) {
        return;
    }

    $repo = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

    $article = $repo->getRepository(Article::class)
                    ->findOneBy(['priority' => $object->getPriority()]);

    // Проверяем в явном виде существует ли объект Article, отвечающий
    // критериям поиска или нет.
    if (null !== $article) {
        $article->setPriority(ArticlePriority::DEFAULT);
        $repo->getManager()->persist($article);
    }
}
```

Если же для вашего приложения такое положение дел является ошибкой, то лучше в явном виде выкидывать исключение:

```
// ...
if (null === $article) {
    throw new Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException('Article was not found.');
}
// ...
```

Comment: К сожалению ни один из вариантов не работает. Значит ошибка кроется глубже )) Но все равно спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Все же первый вариант, предложенный Вами, является половиной решения моего вопроса. Второй половиной являлось то, что не нужно было указывать в файле "Blog.Article.orm.yml "   lifecycleCallbacks: preUpdate: [setPriority] !!!

Comment: Вы вполне можете дать собственный ответ на свой же вопрос, описав там все нюансы (и даже отметить свой ответ зеленой галкой). Возможно это поможет кому-то еще с аналогичной проблемой.